# JSF validateRegex do not work with '#,$,%,(),?,!'

Tags: regex, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am trying to validate a TextArea{basically a Comments box} which would accept almost all characters and special characters with spaces included. The constraint is i only want to use JSF validateRegex tag. I do not want to use validator java class.
IN my code i have done like below

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s_\s-.]*[@#$%!]*$">
```

The textarea does not accept any string with '#,$,%,(),?,!' inspite of including in regex But it accepts only '@'. Can anyone help me out in creating a valid regular expression for this textarea field in JSF.

Comment: You must escape backslashes and can merged the two character classes into one: `"^[\\w\\s.@#$%!-]*$"`. Also, try ``"[\\w\\s.@#$%!-]*"`` since `matches()` seems to be used with the regex.

Comment: No this is not working if i put the inside the jsf tag <f:validateRegex pattern="^[\\w\\s.@#$%!-]*$"> textarea is not accepting anything like String values as "reason description not working !!" or "is reason working ?"

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Which EL impl/version? I remember MyFaces 2.x on TomEE 1.x/2.x requiring double backslashes instead of single backslashes in order to get it to properly parse the regex.

Answer (score -1):

This accepts what you want. Any combination of letters, numbers, whitespace, underscore, minus, ".", "@", "#", "$", "@" and "!".

```
^[\w\s\-.\@#\$%!]*$
```

If you also want "?", "(" and ")" to validate use this:

```
^[\w\s\-.\@#\$%!\?\(\)]*$
```

Answer (score -1):

your regex is fine and you can test it in this site [regexTester](https://regex101.com/), please write your full code for ability to help you.